# Node js queue return elements from an array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to implement a queue in node js.I have an array with elements and i want at every 1 sec to insert a new one.I want to return every time only two elements from queue(at every 5 seconds).I want the queue to continue returning values from where remains.An example.I have an array `[1,2,3,4]`.At every 2 sec i insert a new elemt in array.I return 2 elements from array at every 5 sec.Does anyone know  how to make this work? Here is my code:

```
var queue = require('queue');
var posts=["aaa","bbbb","ccc",'ddd'];
var n=posts.length;
function populateQueue(q) {
  for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
    (function(index) {
      q.push(function(done) {
        console.log('done', posts[index]);
        setTimeout(done, 5000);
  posts.splice(0,2);
      });
    })(i);
  }
}

function insert() {
    posts.push({"name":haiku()});
    cxc();
}


function cxc() {
populateQueue(q2);
}



setInterval(insert,2000);

var q2 = queue({concurrency: 2});
populateQueue(q2);
q2.start();


    function haiku(){

    var adjs = ["autumn", "hidden", "bitter", "misty", "silent", "empty", "dry",
  "dark", "summer", "icy", "delicate", "quiet", "white", "cool", "spring",
  "winter", "patient", "twilight", "dawn", "crimson", "wispy", "weathered",
  "blue", "billowing", "broken", "cold", "damp", "falling", "frosty", "green",
  "long", "late", "lingering", "bold", "little", "morning", "muddy", "old",
  "red", "rough", "still", "small", "sparkling", "throbbing", "shy",
  "wandering", "withered", "wild", "black", "young", "holy", "solitary",
  "fragrant", "aged", "snowy", "proud", "floral", "restless", "divine",
  "polished", "ancient", "purple", "lively", "nameless"]

  , nouns = ["waterfall", "river", "breeze", "moon", "rain", "wind", "sea",
  "morning", "snow", "lake", "sunset", "pine", "shadow", "leaf", "dawn",
  "glitter", "forest", "hill", "cloud", "meadow", "sun", "glade", "bird",
  "brook", "butterfly", "bush", "dew", "dust", "field", "fire", "flower",
  "firefly", "feather", "grass", "haze", "mountain", "night", "pond",
  "darkness", "snowflake", "silence", "sound", "sky", "shape", "surf",
  "thunder", "violet", "water", "wildflower", "wave", "water", "resonance",
  "sun", "wood", "dream", "cherry", "tree", "fog", "frost", "voice", "paper",
  "frog", "smoke", "star"];

  return adjs[Math.floor(Math.random()*(adjs.length-1))]+"_"+nouns[Math.floor(Math.random()*(nouns.length-1))];
}
```

Comment: why the setTimeout(cxc,2000) in insert function?

Comment: I modified..is only cxc()

Answer (score 0):

I have a quick answer to this. Specifically involving your question, but not your code. You have to tell me what your code does, otherwise I can't help you with it. But to do with your question, I have this:

First, setup your initial queue and index.

```
let queue = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    index = 0;
```

Now you have to declare two functions, (1) The one that enqueues values in your array. In my case, I enqueue a random number

```
enqueue = () => {
    queue.push(Math.floor(Math.random()*10));
    console.log(queue);
}
```

The other one gets two values at the current index, and increments the index by 2, once the storing is done. The values are then, returned.

```
get_two_elements = () => {
    let pointed_slice = queue.slice(index, index + 2);
    index += 2;
    console.log(pointed_slice);
    return pointed_slice;
};
```

Finally, to make the contraption work, you have to put timeouts on them like this

```
setInterval(enqueue, 2000);
setInterval(get_two_elements, 5000);
```

Set interval is non-blocking, thus both will happen at almost the sametime with a difference ranging between nanoseconds and milliseconds. This will successfully do what your question sounds like to me.

For reference, I placed a gist on the whole code for you here:

https://gist.github.com/jekku/012eed5ea9c356f8fa29

Comment: And please, practice clean coding. :)

Comment: A side comment, this is written in ES6 : modern javascript. You can rewrite the arrow functions and keywords in old javascript (like your style, es5).